# node.js is consuming much ram by using an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, memory, socket.io

i'm using node.js with io.socket to writing a chat that should save all messages and show them also two new users.
The messages are store into an array of objects.
when i tested it with an amount of 2MB(copy&paste in .txt),my task-manager showed me node.js need about 200MB! From beginning without an message it needs ~19MB.
So i'm asking me if there are any memory-leaks in my code or maybe socket.io saves the array by each use of .emit in an second array?

this is my code:

```
save_object=new Array();
save_object['chat']=new Array();//for the chat room,now there's just this one

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
// client is connected
socket.emit('chat', { time: new Date(), text: 'you are now connected
to the server!' });
//send all msgs on start
socket.emit('all',save_object['chat']);
// user-send event
socket.on('chat', function (data) {
// send msg
io.sockets.emit('chat', { time: new Date(), 
name: data.name || 'anonymous',  text: data.text });
  //save new msg to the array
  save_object['chat'][save_object['chat'].length]=
  new Object({ time:new  Date(), name: data.name || 'anonymous', 
  text: data.text });
});
});
```

Comment: Err..save_object is an array, which means that "save_object['chat']" means you're indexing your array using a string which isn't really a good idea. You might consider making save_object an object? Also, using [] and {} rather than new Array() and new Object() is preferred.

Comment: 19M for a fully fledged Javascript interpreter with a hell lot of libraries used doesn't sound that much... I'm not too used to node.js, but isn't there some kind of debugger you can attach to your program?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i think you missed the  important bit, the process uses 200MB of memory after inserting 2MB worth of text.

Comment: Does it increase any further if you insert another 6MB of text? it should, but not by another 600MB.

Comment: Well, @RobRaisch already pointed out the problems of your string indexing -- also, inserting 2MB worth of text might be happening in let's say 1000 chunks, and each of these 20B chunks would have a 64bit date attached, an easy 10B of username, then underlying interpreter objects, and stack frames -- really, get debugging. It's something impossible to do by looking alone.

Comment: ok now i changed new Object to {...}.this changed nothing at all.so what i was doing exactly is:i put exact 2.8 MB of text data into the input and press send.so i sent just one message.the memory of node.js increased to about 100MB from 19MB at the start start.then i opened another tab.this leads to increase memory too 200Mb and i'm not talking about firefox ;).when i'm opening 10 tabs it stays around 200MB.when i increase to 4Mb and i'm opening a new tab its goes to about 400MB for a while and then it goes to 50MB.so maybe the gc started if there is real much ram used...maybe this is normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't exactly tell you why this use so much memory, but I think using an array to keep the history is a bad idea...
You should at least use a file, and send the messages while reading it (To avoid to have every single message in the memory at the same time), or use a database to store them (If you need to request on the timestamp)...
The file solution is not very difficult to write and would be a little less dangerous...

(By the way, I don't think there is any memory leak in your code... But you will understand that the array will certainly allocate more space that it needs, and the objects you're storing will take more place than in a simple file, due to node, for indexing for example)

Comment: i thought an array just needs the memory it needs,but i'm not an assembler/machine programmer.so does at least memcached/redis just need as much memory as it should(with just an small overhead)?

Comment: I think redis should be motr optimized for this kind of stuff... But don't forget that if Redis is not already launched on your machine, it's gone a take some memory only for running it... I don't know how much, you should try.